# Django CreateView success url with pk from different unrelated model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a django `CreateView` where users can create new words. I also have an unrelated `Song` model, where users can choose to add words from the lyrics of the songs. So I've created a separate `CreateView` for this, so that I can have a different success url. The success url should go back to the song where the user was browsing. But I am struggling to figure out how to pass the pk of this particular object to the `CreateView` of a different model.

This is my special `CreateView`:

```
class CreateWordFromSong(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'vocab/add_custom_initial.html'
    fields = ("target_word","source_word", etc.)
    model = models.Word
    from videos.models import Song

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(CreateWordFromSong, self).form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('videos:song-vocab', kwargs={'pk': song_pk) #how to get song_pk?
```

Everything works when I replace `song_pk` with the actual pk.

I overwrite `form_valid` so that the user can be saved with the new object. Perhaps there is a way I can alter this so that I can also get the `song_pk`? I've played around with it a bit, but without luck.

I get the `song_pk` from my url:

```
path('song/<int:song_pk>/', views.CreateWordFromSong.as_view(), name='create-song'),
```

So I should have access to it. But when I try adding it to my view:

```
class CreateWordFromSong(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView, song_pk)
```

I get the error: `name 'song_pk' is not defined`.

Comment: self.kwargs.get('song_pk')

Comment: @Blackdoor I tried that, but then I get `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: override get_success_url(self) function to return success_url

Answer (score 0):

You could add in `class CreateWordFromSong` instead `success_url` method `get_success_url`

```
    def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse_lazy('videos:song-vocab', kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs.get('song_pk')})
```

It will be work, if action in template with form be like this

```
<form action="{% url 'create-song' song_pk=song.pk %}" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

(Surely a bit lately ...)

I faced a similar case but not sur this matches with your.

I have a list of Mapping objects (children) related to Flow object (parent and ForeignKey).
This list uses the Flow PK.

**urls.py**

```
path('flow/<int:pk>/mapping',
     mappingColumnOneFlowListView.as_view(), name='mapping-details'),
```

On each line of Mapping objects, I got a "delete" button.
After deletion, I want to lead back to the list of the Flow Mapping but couldn't because the PK used in the view lead to the (deleted) Mapping.
Another solution would have consisted in leading to another URL without pk (eg. absolute_url in Model) but this was not what I wanted.

It's surely not the best way to achieve the goal but I found this:

in my DeleteView i added :

```
def get_success_url(self):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']       #  Mapping's PK
    flow_pk = MappingField.objects.filter(
        pk=pk).first().fl_id.pk        # fl_id.pk = Flow's PK (FK)
    return reverse('mapping-details', kwargs={'pk': flow_pk})
```